# Gap exponents and homogeneous functions

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Looking at [this paper on page 1](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/phase/scaling.pdf) how is the first limit obtained? That is, if I have some homogeneous function $g_f(h/t^{\Delta})$, how does setting the gap exponent $\Delta$ to $3/2$ ensure that $$\lim_{x \to 0} g_f(x) = -1/u?$$

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\Delta=3/2$ is useful only to ensure the correct behavior of the second limit.

The first limit is given by the condition $f(t,0)\propto t^2$. Because $f(t,h)=t^2 g_f(h/t^\Delta)$, you directly get that $g_f(x)\to {\rm const}$ for $x\to 0$.

For the sake of completeness, let's do the other case and show that we must have $\Delta=3/2$. You know that $f(0,h)\propto h^{4/3}$. Let's assume that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g_f(x)\propto x^a$, which gives $$\lim_{t\to0}f(t,h)\propto t^2 \Big(\frac{h}{t^\Delta}\Big)^a.$$
In order to get the expected result $f(0,h)\propto h^{4/3}$, we see that $a=4/3$ and $2-a \Delta=0$, which gives $\Delta=3/2$.

(Another way to show the first limit is to assume $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)\propto x^b$ and show that $b=0$.)

Comment: Thanks. Adam, do you mind elaborating specifically on how you get that $\lim {x \to 0} g_f(x)=c$ Why doesn't $c=0$? Edit to comment: looking at your last line I think is what I needed. How *do* you show that $b=0$?

Comment: To fix the constant, you have to know what exactly is the limit. Thankfully, in the mean-field (Ginzburg-Landau) case, you know it : $f(t,0)=-t^2/(8u)$ and up to a numerical factor, the free energy behaves like $-1/u$ as quoted in the paper. The constant is thus $-1/(8u)$, which is non-zero.

Comment: this is circular reasoning, no? We show the limit is fixed by fixing the limit...

Comment: If you have a homogeneous function $g_f(x)$ of order $k>0$ then its limit should be $0$. If it's of order $0$ then it is independent of $x$. (I think I am missing something.) So here is my confusion. If we assume that it's homogeneous of order $0$, then even in the limit that $x$ gets large it shouldn't change.

Comment: @Ignore my last comment, I think I understand. So $g_f(x)$ is not strictly speaking a homogeneous function, but in the large and small limits of $x$ behaves approximately like a homogeneous function...?

Comment: @AlecS: It is not circular (if I understand what part of the reasoning you think is circular), because we do not know a priori what $\Delta$ is. First we assume scale invariance, then we use the two limits we know (at small $t$ and at small $h$) and from that we deduce $\Delta$. The reference you gave just verify that starting from $\Delta=3/2$ is consistent, but in principle you should do it the way I did in the answer. And of course, we always need an input to know what really is the constant, either by using a known limit (as we do here, because we know the mean-field results).

Comment: @AlecS: yes, exactly, $g(x)$ is homogeneous only in certain limits. I was about to address that point right now.